# How to start an activity before resuming the app when restart?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a quiet big application, and sometimes the user uses the `HOME BUTTON` to 'exit' the application or he receives a call etc. but when he clicks again on the icon, the application is resumed.

What I want is everytime somthing like this happens, the app restarts on the login activity (security process) before resuming the previous activity running before he exit the app.

Answer (score 1):

When the HOME button is pushed, I believe your activity's `onStop()` and/or `onPause()` functions will be called.  Override one of these methods and set a member variable to check if your activity was interrupted.  Now override `onResume()` to check that variable to determine if you want to start your login activity.

Hopefully this idea gets you in the right direction.

You might also consider creating a super class that extends Activity and override the `onStop()`/`onPause()`/`onResume()` methods to exhibit this functionality.  That way, all of your activities outside of your login activity can extend this class, allowing you to place the functionality that you desire in exactly one location.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a Extra to any activity you call after login: `intent.putExtra("isLogin", "Yes");`

In every activity you call:

declare a field `boolean isLogin;`

In onCreate:

```
Intent sender = getIntent();
isLogin = sender.getStringExtra("isLogin","No") == "Yes";
```

In the onResume of every activity do this:

```
if(isLogin){
    isLogin = false;
}else{
    callActivityLogin();
}
```

Comment: 2 questions : first of all how he will know if he's logged in or not? and second question is, if i call the login activity it will restart the whole process, i want it to call the running activity

Comment: You may need refactoring your login activity code to handle two situations: First login and subsequents logins. In the second situation, if login successfully, only need call finish() to return to last activity.

Comment: I know but the problem is how to do that programatically, that's why i posted the question